# 指定したURLの内容を表示したい

Tags: python, python3

beutifulsoupを使ってます。指定したURLが出力されません。

```
html = urlopen("https://qiita.com/")
z = html
print(z)
```

上記で、urlopenを使って使ってurlを読み込んでからzに代入し、printで出力しても

```
http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x028199D0
```

のように吐き出されてしまい、`https://qiita.com/`の文字列が出力されません。
どなかたわかるかた教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) はこの場合では [`http.client.HTTPResponse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse) を返すのでそれがそのとおりに表示されています．基本的には[ドキュメンテーション](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls)を読むのが良いでしょうが(あるいは beautifulsoup 使うなら直接[渡](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2647188)せそうですけども)， `https://qiita.com/` が欲しいならおおよそ

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://qiita.com') as r:
    print(r.url)
```

でよいとおもいます．